# How to consider "and" between quantifiers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, logic

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. How would I negate

> $\exists \varepsilon>0$ and $\exists N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $|x_n - a| \ge \varepsilon$

?

I get really confused with the "and" between the quantifiers. It makes me want to change it to an "or". Also, this statement is equivalent to no subsequence of $x_n$ is convergent to $a$, but I am having a difficult time understanding why. If anyone could explain this, and give the negation for the statement above, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\varepsilon>0$ not $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Formally, we would write "there exists $a$ and there exists $b$ such that for all $c$ we have $\phi$" as
$$ \exists a\,\exists b\,\forall c\,\phi$$
If we prepend a negation, it percolates as follows:
$$ \neg\exists a\,\exists b\,\forall c\,\phi\iff\forall a\,\neg \exists b\,\forall c\,\phi\iff \forall a\,\forall b\,\neg \forall c\,\phi
\iff \forall a\,\forall b\, \exists c\,\neg\phi$$

(A more proper wording would be "There exists $a$ for which there exists $b$ for which ...")